# Defining Swift functions that operate on Types instead of values

Tags: types, swift, option-type, type-variables

In Swift, the `?` operator takes `Types` as parameters, instead of values:

```
var z = 42? // won't create an Optional<Int> and won't compile
var z : Int? = 42 // ? takes Int and give a Optional<Int>
```

How can I create my own functions, or operators that work on Type instead of values?

Comment: `?` is not an operator that operates on types, it is part of Swift's "syntactic sugar" on top of `Optional<T>`. In other words, the compiler knows what to do when it sees `?` after a type name. If you wish to write an operator like that, you would need to modify the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve is not possible.

However there is a workaround: you can create a custom operator that given a literal or variable, converts it to an optional. Swift doesn't allow using the `?` character in custom operators, I am choosing a random combination, but feel free to use your own:

```
postfix operator >! {}

postfix func >! <T>(value: T) -> T? {
    return value as T?
}
```

Once done, you can use it as follows (output from playground):

```
10>! // {Some 10}

"Test">! // {Some "Test"}
```